# How to access kivy button ids in py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to work out which button has been selected and then if that button has been selected, assign it to a variable in my python file but I'm not sure how to access the button's id.

The buttons below start off blue [0,0,1,0] and then when pressed, they turn green [0,1,0,1]. My code below is successfully working out which buttons are green and then I've got a print function to show it's working. It's here, where print(self.ids) is that I was to access each id (a through to f) of each of the buttons and store a-f in a variable.

```
class WhatButton(Screen):
    back_color = ObjectProperty()

    def button_pressed(self):
        buttons = [self.ids.a.back_color, self.ids.b.back_color, self.ids.c.back_color,
                          self.ids.d.back_color, self.ids.e.back_color, self.ids.f.back_color]
        counter = 0
        for x in buttons:
            if x == [0, 1, 0, 1]:
                counter += 1
                print(self.ids)
            else:
                pass

        if counter == 0:
            self.none_selected()
        else:
            sm.current = "thank you"
```

Hopefully the above is clear, let me know if it needs any more explanation

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Do you want to do something with all the `Buttons`, or just with the green ones? What do you mean by "store a-f in a variable"?  Are you talking about a list? Do you want to store the `Buttons` in a list? or just the letters a-f?

Comment: I just want to know which button(s) have been pressed (i.e are green) and for each button that is green I want to create a variable equal to "yes". For example, if self.ids.a.back_color was pressed I want to create a variable named a and set it equal to "yes". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create six variable ('a' through 'f'), and set them all to 'no' initially. Then change the green ones to 'yes' in your `button_pressed()` method.

I believe a better way would be to create a dictionary of values with the 'a' through 'f' as the keys. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
def button_pressed(self):
    counter = 0
    self.selected = {}
    for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']:
        if self.ids[x].back_color == [0, 1, 0, 1]:
            counter += 1
            self.selected[x] = 'yes'
        else:
            self.selected[x] = 'no'
    print(self.selected)

    if counter == 0:
        self.none_selected()
    else:
        sm.current = "thank you"
```

Using this approach, you can access any of the values as `self.selected['a']` (or any 'a' through 'f').

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I was having trouble accessing the ids (a through to f) but self.ids[x].back_color is what I was after